# Tablelayoutpane is out of bounce

Tags: c#

im doing a dynamic buttons generation...generating the buttons was not a problem...but the problem is when im find the index of these buttons...lets say  i have a datacell(number of buttons)  = 40....and when i want to show it in the panel...only 20 can be shown and more than 21 and above are out of bounce...

below is my code for finding the index

```
for (int i = 0; i < datacell; i++)
{               
   ctrl[i] = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i]; 
   btn[i] = (Button)ctrl[i];
   panel1.Controls.Add(btn[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The controls can belong to only one container. So when you add the button the the `panel1` it removes form `tableLayoutPanel1`. After that when you add 20 buttons to the `panel1` to `tableLayoutPanel1` already contains another 20, so the 21 is out of bound.

There is technique to solve issues like this:

```
for (int i = datacell - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{               
   ctrl[i] = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i]; 
   btn[i] = (Button)ctrl[i];
   panel1.Controls.Add(btn[i]);
}
```

Comment: may you give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

Comment: is there a way to just show the buttons instead of adding them? thank you

Comment: i only saw the comment but not the code...but now i see it

Comment: To show the control on the form it must be within a container.

Comment: ive tried the tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn[i]);  but it is not working...lets say i want to make 20 buttons visible ...but the other 20 buttons not visible...how can i do that?... i

Comment: have you added your `panel1` to the form or any other container?